# Intel instructions for access to memory which skips cache

Tags: assembly, intel

Is there an instruction using which I can move a variable to/from memory and registers without it being stored in cache? I don't want to disable caching entirely by using CD bit, I only want to do this for individual memory accesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movnt` stores bypass cache, but [`movntdqa` loads may not do that for normal (write-back) memory regions](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVNTDQA.html).

The instruction-set reference manual is very clear that it might not be any different from `movdqa` on WB memory, but IDK what actually happens on any current microarchitectures.

`movntdqa` is intended to speed up stuff like reading from WC video RAM, e.g. copying the results of a hardware video decoder back to main memory.

Comment: Aha, that's last sentence is most enlightening. I could never figure out what possible use `movntdqa reg,[mem]` could have, considering......

Comment: @Johan: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103968/non-temporal-loads-and-the-hardware-prefetcher-do-they-work-together, where my answer has more details and links.  (Including a link to an Intel article illustrating copying from video RAM to main memory, bouncing through a small buffer that stays hot in L1 cache to keep NT loads and NT stores from stepping on each other and flushing with a partial line).