# Examples of non-temporal stores and Intel memory types in code bases

Tags: memory, x86, intel, cpu-architecture

I am trying to understand the behaviour of Intel non-temporal accesses, as well as its different memory types (WC/WT/UC etc.), and I would really like some real-life examples of where these features are used. So far I am aware of the PMDK libraries that use non-temporal stores.

Can you point me to other existing (systems-level) code-bases that use these features? For instance are they used in the Linux kernel?

Comment: glibc memset / memcpy use NT stores for large sizes, to avoid cache pollution.  For understanding reading from WC memory (e.g. video RAM), with SSE4.1 `movntdqa` loads, see https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/copying-accelerated-video-decode-frame-buffers.html.  Note that NT loads are *only* special on WC memory, otherwise they're just slow `movdqa`.  Related: [Non-temporal loads and the hardware prefetcher, do they work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32103968) although I haven't updated that for a while.

Comment: The use-case for NT stores in persistent-memory libraries is their guaranteed eviction of cache.