# Does _mm_stream_load_si128 (movntdqa) modify the memory its argument points to?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse, intrinsics

`_mm_stream_load_si128` is declared as

```
__m128i _mm_stream_load_si128 (__m128i * mem_addr)
```

while `_mm_load_si128` is declared as

```
__m128i _mm_load_si128 (__m128i const* mem_addr)
```

Does the former modify the contents of what `mem_addr` points to? If not, what's the motivation for the non-const declaration?

Comment: @J...: Actually NT *loads* do *not* override the memory-order semantics of the memory region.  `movntdqa` on normal WB memory is just a slow `movdqa` on current CPUs; they don't do anything with the NT hint to try to minimize cache pollution (e.g. by only loading into one "way" of L3 like `prefetchnta` does).  See also [Non-temporal loads and the hardware prefetcher, do they work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32103968) - there is HW prefetch isn't NT-aware, so it wouldn't really make sense to actually bypass cache.  It only does anything on WC memory which is already weakly ordered.

Comment: @J... What you said sounds like it was talking specifically about NT stores (not SSE4.1 NT loads this question is about), especially with the mention of `sfence`.  Like other loads, `movntdqa` loads are not ordered wrt. `sfence`.  [`movntdqa`](//www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movntdqa) is specifically a load.  The SSE2 SIMD-integer NT store is [`movntdq`](//www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movntdq), and like other NT *stores* does do what you say, overriding the strong mem-order semantics of WB memory regions to be more like WC. That's why libc memset / memcpy use it for large copies.  (But not NT loads).

Comment: @PeterCordes Quite right, that's exactly where my mind was.  I missed, oddly enough, that this was about loads, lol.  Must be getting tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* it is declared this way for no reason. See `_mm256_stream_load_si256` and `_mm512_stream_load_si512` that are the same for wider operand, they take `const` argument.

Also in `<smmintrin.h>` that comes with Visual Studio 2015 it is `const`:

```c
/*
 * Load double quadword using non-temporal aligned hint
 */

extern __m128i _mm_stream_load_si128(const __m128i*);
```

Comment: The underlying instruction is a pure load with no side-effects, not even overriding the memory-order semantics of the memory region.  (i.e. it only does anything special on WC memory; on current CPUs the NT hint is fully ignored on WB (normal write-back cacheable) so it's just a slow `movdqa` costing an extra uop.)