# Performance Difference Between _mm512_load_si512 and _mm512_stream_load_si512

Tags: simd, avx512

I'm currently working on a project that involves AVX512 instructions and I have a question regarding the performance differences between `_mm512_load_si512`, `_mm512_loadu_si512`, and `_mm512_stream_load_si512` when copying data from one pointer to another.

As I understand it, `_mm512_load_si512` and `_mm512_stream_load_si512` are designed to work with aligned memory addresses and are expected to perform faster in such cases. However, in my experiments, I haven't observed significant performance differences between these instructions, including `_mm512_loadu_si512` which is meant for unaligned memory.

I found a question on stackoverflow mentioning `_mm512_load_si512` and `_mm512_loadu_si512` but not `_mm512_stream_load_si512`.

My CPU is a Corei7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz, which supports AVX512. I wonder if there are any specific considerations or insights into the performance characteristics of these instructions on this particular processor.

If anyone has experience or knowledge of AVX512 instructions or if there are nuances in memory alignment that I might be overlooking, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

My code (replace `_mm512_stream_load_si512` with `_mm512_load_si512` and `_mm512_loadu_si512`):

```c
// Both dst and src pointers are 64-byte aligned
void copy_data(__m512i *dst, __m512i *src, size_t size)
{
    __m512i block;
    for (; size; dst++, src++, size--)
    {
        block = _mm512_stream_load_si512(src);
        _mm512_stream_si512(dst, block);
    }
}
```

Something to add, replacing `_mm512_stream_si512` with `_mm512_store_si512` or `_mm512_storeu_si512` actually makes a difference. And overall, `_mm512_stream_si512` performs about 1.5x faster in copying data on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`loadu` is as fast as `load` when the data does happen to be aligned at run-time.  The CPU is able to handle it optimistically, taking the fast-path on aligned addresses.**

The only difference is on unaligned data (which is always a cache-line split for 512-bit loads): fault vs. having hardware handle the unaligned case a bit more slowly.  (Using another cycle later in the same load execution unit to access the other cache line.)  Or a larger penalty on page-split (across a 4K boundary), but not a disaster on Skylake and later, i.e. on any Intel CPU new enough for AVX-512.

`loadu` is great when your data is *usually* aligned, but you still want correct behaviour with the occasional unaligned pointer.  Using extra instructions to always reach an alignment boundary or check and branch on misalignment would slow down the aligned case slightly, and be rather inconvenient for copy functions like this which might have different misalignements for the two pointers.  With 512-bit vectors, misalignment has enough penalty to be worth maybe worrying about, unlike with 256-bit vectors where it's tiny.

Faulting is useful for detecting accidentally misaligned data.  But note that compilers can fold `_mm512_load_si512` into a memory source operand for an ALU instruction, which doesn't require alignment.  e.g. using the result as an operand for `_mm512_add_epi32` can end up compiling to `vpaddd zmm0, zmm1, [rdi]`.  A debug build typically won't do that, if you do want to check for use of unaligned data in places you intended not to.

See also *[How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128763/how-can-i-accurately-benchmark-unaligned-access-speed-on-x86-64/45129784#45129784)*

Aligned data being full-speed for alignment-not-required loads/stores has been true since Nehalem for Intel, and since at least Bulldozer-family for AMD, so it's true for all AVX CPUs, not just AVX-512.  On even older CPUs like Core 2, the unaligned instructions like `movdqu` decoded to multiple uops so were always slow.  This is why SSE memory operands for ALU instructions like `addps xmm0, [rdi]` require alignment but AVX memory operands don't (like `vaddps xmm0, xmm0, [rdi]`), *except* with alignment-checking instructions like `vmovaps`.  With legacy SSE code, `_mm_add_epi8(vec, _mm_loadu_si128(ptr))` can't fold into a memory operand for `paddb`, only `_mm_load_si128`.  AVX changes that, even for 128-bit vectors.  (Compilers will use the AVX VEX encodings for 128-bit vectors when you compile with AVX enabled.)

---

#### `stream_load` does nothing on normal (WB) memory regions

Unless something changed with the AVX-512 version, **`stream_load`** is just a slower version of `load` unless you're using it on WC memory (e.g. video RAM).  See *[What is the difference between MOVDQA and MOVNTDQA, and VMOVDQA and VMOVNTDQ for WB/WC marked region?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19035677)*

Unlike NT loads, NT stores *are* useful on normal (WB cacheable) memory regions.  See *[Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy)* re: no-RFO stores (Read For Ownership) and memory bandwidth especially for copying.

A 512-bit aligned store does replace every byte in the cache line (unless you're using a mask and it's not all-ones), but I'm not sure such a store would avoid reading the old contents from DRAM on cache miss.  (i.e. avoiding the read-for-ownership.)  That could be separate from how NT stores bypass cache, e.g. `rep movsb` is supposed to be able to use a no-RFO store protocol while still having its store data end up in cache (because it also writes contiguous data so it knows whole lines will get written.)

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. In my copy function, dst will always be 64-byte aligned (That's why I used `_mm512_stream_si512`), But the src pointer could be misaligned.
Also, the NT stores have a clear advantage in large-size data. But I wonder if they also have this advantage in small or medium size data.

Comment: @MHErshadi: If the next load of the destination could hit in some level of cache, avoid `stream`; NT stores evict from cache if already hot, and don't leave the data in any level of cache.  So it's a disaster for small copies that will be read again soon, or multiple copies to a destination buffer that was already hot in cache.  libc `memcpy` typically uses a fairly large threshold before switching to NT stores, if they do at all.

Comment: If your source data is sometimes misaligned, you might want to use 256-bit vectors.  Especially if you're frequently doing copies too large for cache; 512-bit vectors are probably only faster for copying if data is hot in L1d cache, at least the source data, maybe also destination depending unless it's a small copy.  256-bit vectors have smaller misalignment penalty, especially on Intel CPUs.

Comment: I ran some tests for copying 1GB of data (without threading):
1- Copying data with `_mm512_stream_si512`: 121 msc.
2- Copying data with `_mm512_store_si512`: 140 msc.
3- Copying data with `_mm256_stream_si256`: 372 msc.
4- Copying data with `_mm256_store_si256`: 167 msc.
5- Copying data with `_mm_stream_si128`: 381 msc.
6- Copying data with `_mm_store_si128`: 138 msc.
SSE being better than AVX2 in both cases is weird. Also, its performance in store function is better than the AVX512 version. Is there something wrong with my tests?

Comment: My test results were for the unaligned case. In the aligned case, the results are better. But the order remains the same.
Is it because of the size of the data which can not fit in the cache?

Comment: @MHErshadi: Seems weird; were you controlling for CPU and uncore frequency, e.g. by running some load on another core, like a `pause` loop?  Maybe with fewer instructions per byte, the lower IPC lets hardware P-state management clock down more and that hurts more, if your EPP isn't set to `performance`?  [Slowing down CPU Frequency by imposing memory stress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63399456)  .  Was your source data perhaps 16 or 32 bytes behind the store, modulo 4K, so you maybe had 4K aliasing false dependencies?

Comment: @MHErshadi: If data is aligned by 16 but not by 32, I still wouldn't expect a factor of 2 slowdown.  This is all without unrolling, I assume, compiled by GCC `-O3 -march=x86-64-v4` or something?  If clang, it might be unrolling the loop for you, although I wouldn't expect that to matter when bottlenecked on memory bandwidth with huge copies.  Were these all with the same TLB miss rate, e.g. from transparent hugepages?

Comment: I use GCC with flags: `-O3 -march=native`. I don't think GCC does unrolling by default. Even if it does, I disabled it.

Comment: I created some load for the other cores. The results are slower. But again, the order remains the same. I wonder why NT stores are worse than the normal ones in AVX2 and SSE. By a factor of 2! And THB is enabled on my system.

Comment: @MHErshadi: Perhaps with a mix of loads and stores happening, some partial-line writes are happening with NT stores, like an LFB getting evicted before completing a full line.  512-byte stores make that impossible.  Some unrolling could make it less likely, e.g. doing 2x or 4x 32-byte loads then 2x or 4x 32-byte stores instead of alternating load/store.  That's interesting, though, I wouldn't have guessed it would be that big an effect if that's what it is.

Comment: (Rather than maybe some benchmark methodology effect.  Or Ice Lake silent stores of zeros, https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2020/05/18/icelake-zero-opt.html , but I think microcode updates disabled that, unfortunately.  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2021/06/17/rip-zero-opt.html)

Comment: I used unrolling for AVX2 functions. And finally, its performance equals the AVX512. Although, the `_mm256_store_si256` performance doesn't change with unrolling. Only `_mm256_stream_si256`. I wouldn't have guessed that unrolling is the answer. Also, the performance of SSE reaches AVX512 with unrolling (4x 16-byte load and then 4x 16-byte store). Thank you!

Comment: @MHErshadi: Cool, thanks for testing my guess and sharing the result. IDK if you followed the links in my answer to https://web.archive.org/web/20120918010837/http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/increasing-memory-throughput-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4-streaming-load/ , but that discusses the issue of early eviction of LFBs (a double problem for the use-case it's considering, NT loads from video RAM, NT stores to main memory; for that they got best results bouncing the data to a small buffer that stays hot in L1d cache to avoid mixing NT load with NT store LFB usage.)

Comment: Yes, I have saved that article to read when I got a chance.
I should add something: SSE, AVX2, and AVX512 performance is approximately the same for NT stores on aligned data (with or without unrolling). Things start to become strange when the data is unaligned. Unrolling is very effective in the unaligned case and makes the copy function process the unaligned data as fast as the aligned one.

Comment: @MHErshadi: Misaligned by a multiple of 16 or 32, or are some of the loads cache-line splits?  A cache-line split load would delay the data for the corresponding store.  But stores can't commit to LFBs until after the store instruction retires from the ROB, so I'm not sure why that would matter.  NT stores are weakly ordered so they could potentially commit from the store buffer out of order, but the store buffer entries are allocated in program order, and "graduate" (retire from the ROB) in program order.  If you can make a [mcve] test case, ask a new question with details of your timings.